# Adding security to a CFC file with HTTP_REFERER

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

For extra security on my pages I use HTTP_REFERER within a cfif statement as a check on all my pages to make sure there are no successful direct attacks on any given page.

I am using a cfc file in an Authorize.net post. I do not use cfc or any other plug-ins or apps on my site so this is a first.

I would like to use an cfif statement in the cfc with the pages that call it listed in the cfif statement and if not a listed page,  cfabort the page.

```
  <cfhttpparam name="referer" type="cgi" value="#CGI.HTTP_REFERER#">
```

Comment: Is this a question?  What are you asking?  HTTP Referrer is easily spoofed and not a good form of security.  I believe what you are looking for is CSRF tokens which are built into CF.  http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Cross_Site_Request_Forgery__CSRF_/

Comment: Your google search string is `coldfusion cfc detect calling page`

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is not reliable. Do not use that for any type of security check. http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2008/12/9/Spoofing-CGI-variables--Security-Series-11

Comment: Tnx for the heads up.

Comment: I was looking at the CSRF and I cannot tell if the tokenID is passed from page to page via form or url requests or if it is held in the visitors individual browser session. I do not normally use sessions or cookies.

Comment: Would there be a way of blocking remote calling in the cfc and maybe the cfm pages?

Comment: You could always find suitable cgi and/or application variables to pass as arguments.